# How to initialize and allocate memory to a data-structure and pass to another function

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, header-files

First, I have a data-structure `struct cashier`  that I defined and needed to be initialized. It is put in `queue.c` file for `queue.h` file to use. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnMli.jpg)

```
/* queue.c */
    struct cashier {
        int numberOfCustomersServed; /* This should be initialized to 0 */
        int totalCustomerWaitingTime; /* This should be initialized to 0 */
        float totalAmountReceived; /* This should be initialized to 0 */
       queueADT customerQ; /* This should be initialized to an empty queue */
    };
```

Then, I have a `queue.h` file for the main program `supermarket.c` file. And I defined the type `cashierT` and multiple other queue functions.( `queueADT getEmptyQueue(void);` is to malloc the data-structure "queue" that I created and give memory space to it.) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPxzS.jpg)

```
  /* queue.h*/
     typedef struct cashier cashierT;
```

In the main program `supermarket.c` , I initialize the cashier structure.

```
/* supermarket.c*/
cashierT initCashier(void){
    cashierT x;
    x.numberOfCustomersServed=0;
    x.totalCustomerWaitingTime=0;
    x.totalAmountReceived=0.0;
    x.customerQ=getEmptyQueue();

    return x;
  };
```

But then, I get some errors: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoXUH.jpg)

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Heta/Desktop/CLionHWQ2/supermarket.c:12:10: error: return type is an incomplete type
 cashierT initCashier(void){
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
/cygdrive/c/Users/Heta/Desktop/CLionHWQ2/supermarket.c: In function 'initCashier':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Heta/Desktop/CLionHWQ2/supermarket.c:13:14: error: storage size of 'x' isn't known
     cashierT x;
              ^
```

But if I copy and paste the whole `struct cashier` in `supermarket.c` the error disappeared. [Ref 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkJpY.jpg) 
 [Ref 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5ikB.jpg).  Why is there such a problem and how can I fix it if I want to keep the `struct cashier` and initialization in `queue.c` ?

Comment: You probably needs to be returning a `cashierT *` (pointer to a `cashierT`).  If you return a structure, the code must know the details of the layout of the structure.  It doesn't need that information with just a pointer — until and unless it needs to dereference the structure.

Comment: I think you need to allocate some memory first `cashierT* x = malloc(sizeof(cashierT))` and use pointers like Jonathan said.
Also I would use a pointer for customerQ aswell and allocate memory for it in the `getEmptyQueue()`